# Twitter Typeahead Custom Datum

Tags: twitter, typeahead.js

I have followed several articles and SO posts...so much confusion.

Seems Bootstrap Typeahead is not the same as twitter typeahead for starters??

Anyway I have the following simple code:

```
  // NOTE: Initiate auto-complete
  $('#edit-keyword').typeahead({
    remote: '/products/autocomplete.json/%QUERY', 
    wildcard: '%QUERY'

  }).bind('typeahead:selected', function(object, datum) {
    console.log(datum);
  });
```

Works fine but datum contains only the "textual" value entered into the text field. Whereas JSON is returning both an ID of the keyword and the textual version. I need to obtain that ID value inside the selection handler.

Any ideas? Links to articles which explain how this might be done would be very handy, similar to this (which is for bootstrap typeahead):

http://tatiyants.com/how-to-use-json-objects-with-twitter-bootstrap-typeahead/

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that providing the valueKey: 'name' as part of the configuration forces the whole dataum object to be populated instead of just the default textual value.

HTH

Comment: Thank you, this got it for me. I'm using typeahead 0.9.3. I had a JSON array of  objects coming back with properties countryName and isoCode. I just set valueKey to countryName, and it uses that to show in the dropdown, and then returns the whole datum in typeahead:selected method.